# Where to substitue"ActiveSupport::SecureRandom" for "SecureRandom" in the Devise code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm working on a Windows machine and am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2 and I just installed the Devise gem for authentication.

When I try to sign in with a previously registered user, the following error appears:

```
NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create

uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::SecureRandom
```

Googling around, I've read that this is due to "ActiveSupport" being deprecated in Rails 3.2, and that the solution is to substitute every appearance of "ActiveSupport:SecureRandom" in the code for only "SecureRandom".

I have been looking for that string of code ("ActiveSupport:SecureRandom") but haven't been able to find it. Where is it? In which file?

Answer (score 0):

You could put this code at the top in devise.rb

```
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom = SecureRandom
```

Works for me